# Exclude Internet Explorer for Google Pagespeed

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, gzip, google-pagespeed

I enabled google page speed for a website for optimization. The site works fine for most browsers except for Internet Explorer where it shows broken characters as shown in attachment.

Is there a way or htaccess rule to deactivate Google Pagespeed specifically for Internet Explorer?

[image: Internet Explorer Screenshot]

Comment: Please, can you post the content of your `.htaccess` file? You might be messing a header statement.

Comment: Do you declare the charset in your page `<head>` section? If no, can you try to add `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />`?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> is already there